# How to save multiple arguments to a Map?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, immutability

I am using arguments from command line which is in the form of an Array and I would like to convert that into a Map.

So for example when I run my code with `scala abc.scala A 10 B 20 C 30` I want to have a `Map(A->10, B->20, C->30)`. Also I can use only val so I cannot reassign it because it is immutable. I am using the following piece of code unsuccessfully:

```
val names = args.filter(x => for(i <- 0 to args.length-1) i%2==0)
val numbers = args.partition(args(i) => i%2==1)
names.zip(numbers).toMap
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `grouped`:

```
args.grouped(2).map { case Array(n,v) => (n,v) }.toMap
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `for` in completely the wrong way.  That runs a new iteration every element of your args.  If you want an index that you can work off of, try `args.zipWithIndex` (which pairs an index with each element).  Alternatively, look at `args.grouped(2)`.